# Unable to find artifact "copy-protoc:generate-sources"

Tags: eclipse, maven, protocol-buffers

I'm using Google's Protocol Buffers in a project. We use Maven to compile the protobufs automatically ( based on http://vlkan.com/blog/post/2015/11/27/maven-protobuf/ )

Maven gave us tree errors which we were able to solve by installing Maven Plugins on our Eclipse installation. But there is one error we can't solve :

```
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.9:copy:copy-protoc:generate-sources
```

This error comes and goes apparently "randomly" and it doesn't break the compilation: everything works perfectly fine.
Here is the maven plugin configuration responsible for this problem:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <executions>
ERROR HERE - <execution>
                <id>copy-protoc</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <artifactItems>
                        <artifactItem>
                            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
                            <artifactId>protoc</artifactId>
                            <version>3.0.0-beta-3</version>
                            <classifier>${os.detected.classifier}</classifier>
                            <type>exe</type>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                        </artifactItem>
                    </artifactItems>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

I tried deleting the .m2 folder or looking for more plugins to no avail.

How to remove that error from Eclipse? Thanks

**Edit 1 , the whole stacktrace:**

```
Unable to find artifact. (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.9:copy:copy-protoc:generate-sources)

org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to find artifact.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.dependency.fromConfiguration.AbstractFromConfigurationMojo.getArtifact(AbstractFromConfigurationMojo.java:265)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.dependency.fromConfiguration.AbstractFromConfigurationMojo.getProcessedArtifactItems(AbstractFromConfigurationMojo.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.dependency.fromConfiguration.CopyMojo.doExecute(CopyMojo.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.dependency.AbstractDependencyMojo.execute(AbstractDependencyMojo.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1362)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1360)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.build(MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.java:52)
    at com.ianbrandt.tools.m2e.mdp.core.MdpBuildParticipant.executeMojo(MdpBuildParticipant.java:133)
    at com.ianbrandt.tools.m2e.mdp.core.MdpBuildParticipant.build(MdpBuildParticipant.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.build(MavenBuilderImpl.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactNotFoundException: Failure to find com.google.protobuf:protoc:exe:3.0.0-beta-3 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced

Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

Then, install it using the command: 
    mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.google.protobuf -DartifactId=protoc -Dversion=3.0.0-beta-3 -Dpackaging=exe -Dfile=/path/to/file

Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
    mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.google.protobuf -DartifactId=protoc -Dversion=3.0.0-beta-3 -Dpackaging=exe -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]


  com.google.protobuf:protoc:exe:3.0.0-beta-3

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=false)

    at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:218)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:545)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.dependency.fromConfiguration.AbstractFromConfigurationMojo.getArtifact(AbstractFromConfigurationMojo.java:257)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to find com.google.protobuf:protoc:exe:3.0.0-beta-3 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:212)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Failure to find com.google.protobuf:protoc:exe:3.0.0-beta-3 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
    ... 44 more
```

**Edit 2 , The Effective POM:**

```
Effective POMs, after inheritance, interpolation, and profiles are applied:

<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- Generated by Maven Help Plugin on 2016-06-01T01:19:06                  -->
<!-- See: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/                -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- ====================================================================== -->

<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- Effective POM for project 'com.GroupName:ProjectName:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT'  -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- ====================================================================== -->

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.GroupName</groupId>
  <artifactId>ProjectName</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>ProjectName</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <build-helper-maven-plugin.version>1.9.1</build-helper-maven-plugin.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <maven-antrun-plugin.version>1.8</maven-antrun-plugin.version>
    <maven-dependency-plugin.version>2.9</maven-dependency-plugin.version>
    <maven-shade-plugin.version>2.4.3</maven-shade-plugin.version>
    <os-maven-plugin.version>1.5.0.Final</os-maven-plugin.version>
    <os.detected.arch>x86_64</os.detected.arch>
    <os.detected.classifier>windows-x86_64</os.detected.classifier>
    <os.detected.name>windows</os.detected.name>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <protobuf-java-format.version>1.2</protobuf-java-format.version>
    <protobuf.input.directory>E:\Development\GroupName\ProjectFolder/proto</protobuf.input.directory>
    <protobuf.output.directory.cpp>E:\Development\GroupName\ProjectFolder\target/libcpp</protobuf.output.directory.cpp>
    <protobuf.output.directory.java>E:\Development\GroupName\ProjectFolder\target/generated-sources</protobuf.output.directory.java>
    <protobuf.version>3.0.0-beta-3</protobuf.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
      <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0-beta-3</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.protobuf-java-format</groupId>
      <artifactId>protobuf-java-format</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>E:\Development\GroupName\ProjectFolder\src\main\java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>E:\Development\GroupName\ProjectFolder\src\main\scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>E:\Development\GroupName\ProjectFolder\src\test\java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>E:\Development\GroupName\ProjectFolder\target\classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>E:\Development\GroupName\ProjectFolder\target\test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <extensions>
      <extension>
        <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0.Final</version>
      </extension>
    </extensions>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>E:\Development\GroupName\ProjectFolder\src\main\resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>E:\Development\GroupName\ProjectFolder\src\test\resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <directory>E:\Development\GroupName\ProjectFolder\target</directory>
    <finalName>ProjectName</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
          <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
              <pluginExecutions>
                <pluginExecution>
                  <pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <versionRange>[1.7,)</versionRange>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </pluginExecutionFilter>
                  <action>
                    <ignore />
                    <execute>
                      <runOnConfiguration>true</runOnConfiguration>
                      <runOnIncremental>true</runOnIncremental>
                    </execute>
                  </action>
                </pluginExecution>
              </pluginExecutions>
            </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.8</source>
              <target>1.8</target>
              <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.8</source>
              <target>1.8</target>
              <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testResources</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testResources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-protoc</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
                  <artifactId>protoc</artifactId>
                  <version>3.0.0-beta-3</version>
                  <classifier>${os.detected.classifier}</classifier>
                  <type>exe</type>
                  <outputDirectory>E:\Development\GroupName\ProjectFolder\target</outputDirectory>
                </artifactItem>
              </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>exec-protoc</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <target>
                <property name="protoc.filename" value="protoc-3.0.0-beta-3-${os.detected.classifier}.exe" />
                <property name="protoc.filepath" value="E:\Development\GroupName\ProjectFolder\target/${protoc.filename}" />
                <chmod file="${protoc.filepath}" perm="ugo+rx" />
                <mkdir dir="E:\Development\GroupName\ProjectFolder\target/generated-sources" />
                <mkdir dir="E:\Development\GroupName\ProjectFolder\target/libcpp" />
                <path id="protobuf.input.filepaths.path">
                  <fileset dir="E:\Development\GroupName\ProjectFolder/proto">
                    <include name="**/*.proto" />
                  </fileset>
                </path>
                <pathconvert property="protobuf.input.filepaths" pathsep=" " refid="protobuf.input.filepaths.path" />
                <exec failonerror="true" executable="${protoc.filepath}">
                  <arg value="-I" />
                  <arg value="E:\Development\GroupName\ProjectFolder/proto" />
                  <arg value="--java_out" />
                  <arg value="E:\Development\GroupName\ProjectFolder\target/generated-sources" />
                  <arg value="--cpp_out" />
                  <arg value="E:\Development\GroupName\ProjectFolder\target/libcpp" />
                  <arg line="${protobuf.input.filepaths}" />
                </exec>
              </target>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>add-classes</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>E:\Development\GroupName\ProjectFolder\target/generated-sources</source>
              </sources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-clean</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-site</id>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>site</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>E:\Development\GroupName\ProjectFolder\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>site-deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>E:\Development\GroupName\ProjectFolder\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>E:\Development\GroupName\ProjectFolder\target\site</outputDirectory>
          <reportPlugins>
            <reportPlugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            </reportPlugin>
          </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <outputDirectory>E:\Development\GroupName\ProjectFolder\target\site</outputDirectory>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

Comment: Show the log/stack trace.

Comment: Added the whole stack trace.

Comment: Does it work okay in a console?

Comment: There are two issue here: the expection is crap, it does not tell what artifact causes the problem (file an issue, I can fix that). Second, does it really resolve to [this](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3Acom.google.protobuf%20AND%20a%3Aprotoc). What is the value of `${os.detected.classifier}`?. Run `mvn help:effective-pom` show us necessary bits.

Comment: Yes it works okay in a console, the problem certainly comes from Eclipse POM's validation.

Comment: Added Run mvn help:effective-pom

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for posting this question. I was facing a similar issues in my pom.
It got resolved once I changed maven dependency plugin version to 3.0.0

Another thing that I wasn't sure about was the maven-dependency plugin's os detected classifier, so I gave it manually. I see that you have also defined it manually so updating the dependency plugin itself should resolve this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The issue persist even after updating to version 3. It disappeared for a while, and then it's back. "Random" like I said in the question.

Comment: @Guillaume F. I have done one more thing, which is probably not a very good thing, but it worked for me anyways. I switched to Netbeans/IntelliJ and my errors got resolved automatically. I am able to build the code and .proto files have also started compiling to java classes now.

Comment: The issue is only present on Eclipse.