# Maven POM.xml error in spring STS

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am getting the below error in my pom.xml file -

Failure to transfer org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:pom:0.9.0 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:pom:0.9.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out

I have just downloaded STS. When creating a Maven project i am getting this error.

I searched here and create the settings.xml file in /.m2 folder.

Comment: Please go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701532/force-maven-update The dependency [exists](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jvnet/jaxb2/maven2/maven-jaxb2-plugin/0.9.0/), so check your proxy settings and firewall maybe as well.

Comment: I've had a similar issue, see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37566525/unable-to-find-artifact-copy-protocgenerate-sources Apparently this is a bug in the Maven Eclipse plugins. It disappeared when I updated Eclipse to Neon.